# update() function make accessor executed twice in laravel

Tags: laravel, model, accessor

'elpased_time' field have integer value but It need long time to calculate. So I want to calculate only when it is null. I put the code in model's accessor. when I put update() into accessor, accessor executed twice.

PHP 7.1

Laravel 5.7

```
class Process extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    ...

    protected $guarded = [];

    ...

    public function getElapsedTimeAttribute(): ?int
    {
        // if the value is in DB, return it)
        if ($this->attributes['elapsed_time'] !== null) {
            return $this->attributes['elapsed_time'];
        }

        logger('In Process::getDelayTimeAttribute()');
        $elapsedTime = VERYLONGTAKENFUNCTION();


        $this->attributes['elapsed_time'] = $elapsedTime;
        $this->update(['elapsed_time' => $elapsedTime]);
        logger('value saved...');

        return $elapsedTime;
    }

    ...
}
```

```
$ php artisan tinker

>>> App\Process::find(1)->elapsed_time
=> 1116
```

```
--- laravel.log

local.DEBUG: In Process::getDelayTimeAttribute()
local.DEBUG: In Process::getDelayTimeAttribute()
local.DEBUG: value saved...
local.DEBUG: value saved...
```

I think '$process->elapsed_time' may call itself twice recursively.

because VERYLONGTAKENFUNCTION() need long execution time, it took double. I hope It will run just once.

- Using save() instead of update(), an error occured: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '7034' for key 'PRIMARY'
  (SQL: insert into `processes` (`id`, ... ) values (7034, ...)
- Using function ( getElapsedTime() ) instead of accessor, it works fine.

Comment: Is `elpased_time` an actual field in your table?

Comment: Yes, @RossWilson. `processes` table has `eplased_time int(11)` field.

Comment: it could be the `update` function that retrieves the `elapsed_time` variable again. Somewhere in the code it calls the `->elapsed_time` again so thats why you see it twice

Comment: also you might want to just create a function named `calculateElapsedTime()` and do your logic that way, since it feels a bit odd to update a model while you're basically just doing `$model->elapsed_time`